# End - extension in the complete theory that isn't elementary extension

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

Could you prompt me,  example of complete theory,  that has, say,  two models, $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$, that $\mathfrak{A} \le_{end} \mathfrak{B}$, but $\mathfrak{A} \npreceq \mathfrak{B}$?

For example,  for this reason I leave considering of arithmetic vector spaces,  with different dimensions,  say,  R^3 and R^7 - R^7 is elementary extension of R^3, so it isn't fit.

Comment: What do you mean by "end-extension"?

Comment: To expand on Eric's comment, the notion of end extension only makes sense for certain types of structures, like models of $\mathsf{PA}$ or $\mathsf{ZFC}$. There is no notion of "end extension" for vector spaces, for example. So you need to specify what type of theory you're looking at. Maybe you just want an example of structures with $\mathfrak{A}\subseteq\mathfrak{B}$ and $\mathfrak{A}\equiv\mathfrak{B}$ but $\mathfrak{A}\not\preccurlyeq\mathfrak{B}$?

Comment: I consider end - extension by likewise definition: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_extension

Comment: And when I sad about vector spaces I meant v.s. with lexicographic order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L = \{\leq\}$, and let $T$ be the complete theory of $N = (\mathbb{N}^*,\leq)$, the reverse order on the natural numbers. Let $M = ((\mathbb{N}\cup \{-1\})^*,\leq)$, so $M$ adds a new maximal element $-1$ on top of $N$.

Then $M$ is an end extension of $N$, and it is also a model of $T$ since it is isomorphic to $N$, but it is not an elementary extension: let $\varphi(x)$ be the formula $\forall y(y\leq x)$ which expresses that $x$ is a maximal element. Then $N\models \varphi(0)$ but $M\not\models \varphi(0)$.

Comment: Thanks! But is there some more complicated example of model,  with some operations?  Or for answer on that question I should ask new question?

Comment: @Timur You'll have to be more precise. The answer to "is there some more complicated example" is almost always "yes". I always strive to give the simplest possible example, because it is the easiest to understand. If you want a more complicated example, you should try to explain what specific features you're looking for and why.

Comment: could you please take a look at my new rewrited question:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4046939/end-extension-example-for-complete-theory

Comment: oh this is interesting, is OP's link a commonly used definition of "end extension"? the wiki page doesn't seem to have any references (+1)

Comment: I've met the notion of "end extension" $M\leq_{\text{end}} N$ both in the context of linearly ordered theories (with a distinguished symbol $\leq$, where elements of $N\setminus M$ cannot be $\leq$ elements of $M$) and set theories (with a distinguished symbol $\in$, where elements of $N\setminus M$ cannot be $\in$  elements of $M$). The definition given in the wikipedia article seems like a natural generalization of both these definitions, but I don't recall seeing it in the literature. @AtticusStonestrom

Comment: something interesting to think about! I wonder if there are any particularly nice or natural examples outside of those two classes of theory