# End extension example for complete theory

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

I elaborate my previous question about example of complete theory,  that has two models, $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$, that $\mathfrak{A} \le_{end} \mathfrak{B}$, but $\mathfrak{A} \npreceq \mathfrak{B}$.

Could you prompt me,  now,  such example with predicate symbol in its signature?  Or,  maybe with function. Cause I need to do some task(I will do it myself:),  about checking of keeping truth over end extensions for non sigma - formulas,  so I need some theories,  where I would check it for formulas with $\forall$ quantifiers, in way,  it would be more convenient.

Update: And, if it possible, can it be theories on some intervals, like (0,3) or something like that? Initially I wanted to take theory of dense linear order without endpoints over field of rationals with only multiplication and without addition, but I ain't sure, that it will be right.

Comment: You should really specify the data here. I suppose you are talking about theories of linear orders? Are those pure linear orders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your original question ($\mathfrak{B}=$ $\mathbb{N}$ with the reversed order as an end extension of $\mathfrak{A}_m=\mathbb{N}_{>m}$ with the reversed order, for your favorite $m\in\mathbb{N}$) can be modified in various ways. Specifically, say that a $k$-ary relation $R$ on $\mathbb{N}$ is $m$-**shift invariant** iff we have $R(a_1+m,...,a_k+m)\iff R(a_1,...,a_k)$, and say that a $k$-ary function $f$ on $\mathbb{N}$ is $m$-**shift invariant** iff we have $f(a_1+m,..., a_k+m)=f(a_1,...,a_k)+m$. Given any $m$-shift invariant relations and functions, we have that the expansion of $\mathfrak{B}$ by those relations and functions is an elementary equivalent end extension of the expansion of $\mathfrak{A}_m$ by (the restrictions of) those same relations and functions, while of course this extension is not elementary. (Shift invariance comes in when we argue for elementary equivalence - in fact, the relevant structures are isomorphic, via the "shift-by-$m$" map.)

For example, the unary relation naming the even numbers is $m$-shift invariant for every even $m$, while the function $a*b=\max\{a,b\}+\vert b-a\vert$ is $m$-shift invariant for every $m$ whatsoever.

I suspect this sort of minor tweak won't help you too much, but without knowing more about your particular goal it's not clear where to look for a better example. (If you're familiar with for

Comment: Thanks! But are you sure, that adding such functions, as "$*$" is possible? Should I add for that relations and functions some new symbols in signature, like "max" or "modulo"? .And, even if it is possible, are you sure that theory with such relations and functions will be complete? For example, theory of reals with addition and multiplication is complete, but theory of rationals is complete only with addition.

Comment: @Timur "are you sure, that adding such functions, as "$*$" is possible?" I don't know what you mean. I can always add functions/relations to a given structure; what's your concern? "Should I add for that relations and functions some new symbols in signature, like "max" or "modulo"?" Yes this is *how* you expand a structure by some new relations/functions: add new **symbols** corresponding to them. "are you sure that theory with such relations and functions will be complete?" Trivially: I'm taking the theory to be $Th(\mathfrak{B})$. No need to think about theories at all here, just structures.

Comment: Could you, please, take a look at update, that I added to my question? It is not so necessarily, but could it be theory, defined this way, on intervals?

Comment: @Timur You say are looking for examples "Cause I need to do some task". Maybe you should ask the question you really want to solve (about this "task") rather than asking a series of questions in which the goal changes each time. If you want to solve the problem on your own, just ask for a hint rather than a full solution. People will respect this.